# Create Google-Matrix and calculate its page-rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The damping factor is $d=\frac{4}{5}$ and the network is the following:

$1\rightarrow2,3\\2\rightarrow3,4\\3\rightarrow1,2,4,6\\4\\5\rightarrow2\\6\rightarrow5$

**What I have done so far**

The google matrix is defined as $L_d=d(L+\frac{1}{n}D)+(1-d)\frac{1}{n}S$.

$$d_{ij}= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & deg_+(j)>0 \\
1 & deg_+(j)=0 \\
\end{array}
\right., s_{ij}=1$$ and $$l_{ij}= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{deg_+(j)} & i\in\Gamma_+(j) \\
0 & i\notin\Gamma_+(j) \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

From my calculations I got:
$$ L_d= \left(\begin{matrix}0&0&\frac{7}{30}&\frac{1}{6}&0&0\\\frac{13}{30}&0&\frac{7}{30}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{5}{6}&0\\\frac{13}{30}&\frac{13}{30}&0&\frac{1}{6}&0&0\\0&\frac{13}{30}&\frac{7}{30}&\frac{1}{6}&0&0\\0&0&0&\frac{1}{6}&0&\frac{5}{6}\\0&0&\frac{7}{30}&\frac{1}{6}&0&0\end{matrix}\right) $$

**My questions**

1. Is the google matrix correctly calculated?
2. How can I calculate the page rank? I found the definition "The page rank is the unique eigenvector of $L_d$ to the eigenvalue 1". However when I calculate the eigenvalues of the characteristic polynomial, there is no eigenvalue of 1. Then I tried to just use the eigenvalue 1 to calculate the vector, what resulted in the null vector. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question?

Comment: I asked myself the same..